# Can an object have an array as its [[prototype]] in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototype

Have a look at this code please

```js
var arr = [1, 2];
var obj = Object.create(arr); // should create a new object with arr as its prototype
console.log(obj) // logs [1, 2]
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)) // logs [1, 2]
```

Shouldn't `obj` be an empty object with its `[[prototype]]` bound to `arr` ? Contrary to expectations, `obj` is logged as the array `[1, 2]`:

[image]

And what does it mean to set an array as `[[prototype]]` of an object?

Comment: What console are you using? It *is* an empty object, only your console might display it in a weird matter. You might try whether `console.dir` gets a different result.

Comment: "*what does it mean to set an array as `[[prototype]]` of an object?*" - there is no hidden meaning. It's just an object with an odd prototype. You'll hardly need this anywhere - just like an object that inherits from a function.

Comment: Have a look please http://i.imgur.com/vpeSCd2.png

Comment: This looks like Chrome Devtools, but not exactly - what version are you using? I cannot reproduce - it does log `[] -> __proto__: Array[2]` for me

Comment: I am using Google Chrome version 46.0.2490.80 (64-bit) on Ubuntu.

Comment: That's odd. The very same version (on Win7 though) gives me [these results](http://i.stack.imgur.com/HcUCv.png)

Comment: Firefox (Dev edittion 43.0a2) on the same machine gives a sane output, have a look http://i.imgur.com/H1mxio7.png

Comment: Hm, you may consider reporting this as a devtools bug with Chrome